# Unit test an ActionResult

Tags: c#, mocking, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm trying to test a custom ActionResult but I don't get it to work.
I'm writing a file to the response stream, so what I would like to do in my unit test is read the response and verify if it's correct.

Here's the method I want to test:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Start writing the file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">The response object.</param>
    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        // Convert the IList<T> to a datatable.
        dataTable = list.ConvertToDatatable<T>();

        // Add the header and the content type required for this view.
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
        response.ContentType = base.ContentType;

        // Gets the current output stream.
        var outputStream = response.OutputStream;

        // Create a new memorystream.
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteDataTable(memoryStream);
            outputStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
    }
```

I've already tried the following in Unit tests:

```
        HttpContextBaseMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        HttpRequestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        HttpResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        HttpContextBaseMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(HttpRequestMock.Object);
        HttpContextBaseMock.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(HttpResponseMock.Object);

        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        var controller = new CsvActionResultController();
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(HttpContextBaseMock.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
        controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(HttpContextBaseMock.Object, new RouteData()), routes);

        var result = controller.ExportToCSV();
```

However, I don't get it to work.

In case it's needed, here's the full source (without constructors) of the CsvActionResult:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Start writing the file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response">The response object.</param>
    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        // Add the header and the content type required for this view.
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
        response.ContentType = base.ContentType;

        // Gets the current output stream.
        var outputStream = response.OutputStream;

        // Create a new memorystream.
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteDataTable(memoryStream);
            outputStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
    }

    #endregion Methods

    #region Helper Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Writes a datatable to a given stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to write to.</param>
    private void WriteDataTable(Stream stream)
    {
        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding);

        // Write the header only if it's indicated to write.
        if (includeRowHeader)
        { WriteHeaderLine(streamWriter); }

        // Move to the next line.
        streamWriter.WriteLine();

        WriteDataLines(streamWriter);

        streamWriter.Flush();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Writes the header to a given stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="streamWriter">The stream to write to.</param>
    private void WriteHeaderLine(StreamWriter streamWriter)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            WriteValue(streamWriter, dataColumn.ColumnName);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Writes the data lines to a given stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="streamWriter"><The stream to write to./param>
    private void WriteDataLines(StreamWriter streamWriter)
    {
        // Loop over all the rows.
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            // Loop over all the colums and write the value.
            foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
            { WriteValue(streamWriter, dataRow[dataColumn.ColumnName].ToString()); }
            streamWriter.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Write a specific value to a given stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The stream to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to write.</param>
    private void WriteValue(StreamWriter writer, String value)
    {
        writer.Write(value);
        writer.Write(delimeter);
    }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
I'm new to mocking.

Kind regards,

Comment: What exact exception you getting? What's your ExportToCSV() Action looks like? How does is call the WriteFile() method?

Comment: Well, let's say that ExportToCSV is adding a file to the response, using "content-dispotion".

I would like me unit test to get the entire response stream to which my Action Result is writing and check the whole response stream (all  properties from it). But I don't get it to work.

For example:

Response.OutputStream is always null.
Response.ContentStream is awalys null.

I would like to check for example the filename, the content type, ...


Kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would not go down the path to ensure your web Response contains the appropriate result especially in a Unit Testing scenario. If you want the fully functional test with the real web interaction (i.e contains all relevant properties populated with correct values), I would use an Acceptance Test/UI Test to make sure you have the correct behaviour of a file export.

**HOWEVER** a Unit Test would be still important as you want to verify things in isolation and make sure you get quick feedback on the behaviour you implemented. The way write the these Unit test are slightly different knowing that you don't have the full ASP.NET runtime execution during Unit Testing.

So in regards to you comment

> For example: Response.OutputStream is always null.
>   Response.ContentStream is awalys null.

Note that just stubbing out HttpContextBase, HttpResponseBase, and assigning it to ControllerContext, does not mean that it would have all the necessary properties for such as OutputStream, ContentStream , Response headers, content types are set during Unit Testing execution context. You are working on a proxied/mocked/stubbed objects (i.e HttpResponseMock ) provided by the Moq.Mock so you don't get those properties available for you as you would normally get during the normal execution of the ASP.NET web. This is why during the Unit Test execution context, you see these properties return null.

You can make thes properties not to return null. You can stub those properties as you would normally do with other virtual properties.

```
  httpResponseBaseStub.SetupGet(x => x.OutputStream).Returns(new Mock<Stream>().Object);
  httpResponseBaseStub.SetupGet(x => x.ContentType).Returns("text/csv");
```

All properties, methods in HttpResponseBase are virtual so you can use the Moq.Mock to provide the fake representation of all those properties to your SUT. There are advance mocking technique such as [AutoMocking](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/), which may help you to remove some unnecessary mocking but make all those properties returned to you by default, but I will not go into that detail.

BUT, what this is not what you probably expect, because stubbinh/faking values like I have described above does not really add value to what you need to verify in your Unit test. They are just fake values.

So what would be the next best approach?

I think it would be better to verify the behaviour of your ExportToCSV by verifying some of the key HttpResponseBase properties called with expected values. For example, in your Unit Test, it would be sufficient for you to verify certain HttpResponse properties called with expected values like below.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CsvActionResultController_ExportToCSV_VerifyResponsePropertiesAreSetWithExpectedValues()
    {
        var sut = new HomeController();
        var httpResponseBaseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

        //This would return a fake Output stream to you SUT 
        httpResponseBaseMock.Setup(x => x.OutputStream).Returns(new Mock<Stream>().Object);
        var httpContextBaseStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpContextBaseStub.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(httpResponseBaseMock.Object);
        var controllerContextStub = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        controllerContextStub.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(httpContextBaseStub.Object);
        sut.ControllerContext = controllerContextStub.Object;

        var result = sut.Index();

        httpResponseBaseMock.VerifySet(x => x.ContentType = "text/csv");
        httpResponseBaseMock.Verify(x => x.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=somefile.csv"));

        //Any other verifications...
    }
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359260/how-to-unit-test-this-method-in-c) is another example, but slightly different approach using similar verifications. With what I have described and by testing ActionResult type is a FileContentResult, you can probably come up with a reasonably good Unit Test.

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(FileContentResult));
```

**Update** (included WriteFile method)

```
    protected void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        // Add the header and the content type required for this view.
        string format = string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "somefile.csv");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", format);
        response.ContentType = "text/csv"; //if you use base.ContentType, 
        //please make sure this return the "text/csv" during test execution.

        // Gets the current output stream.
        var outputStream = response.OutputStream;

        // Create a new memorystream.
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // WriteDataTable(memoryStream);
            outputStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately, I do receive an error message.

Message: Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.ContentType = "text/csv"

Location:

    httpResponseBaseMock.VerifySet(x => x.ContentType = "text/csv");


Any idea why and how this can be resolved?



Kr,

Comment: I've added the source of CsvActionResult (without constructors) to the original question.

Comment: When you run the application, check the value of base.ContentType. During the Unit Test, this must match the value you assigned to x.ContentType. In my example, my SUT sets the ContentType as "text/csv". For example, response.ContentType = "text/csv"; Your base.ContentType should return the "txt/csv" during the test execution. I have also updated the code with my version of the WriteFile() method

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer but I don't get it. Why should I set it to text/csv instead of using base.ContentType (in my constructor the base.Contentype is set - but I haven't provided the code, so that's my mistake). Even with your code, the unit test keeps throwing the same error message. And if I debug it, I never come into the WriteFile method of my controller, so I do think something is wrong over there.

Comment: I think something as controller.execute() must be used passing the controller context, and I've tried that approach but I'm failing at it.